# テキストファイルの最初4文字の文字化け

Tags: テキストファイル, sed

テキストファイルをエクセルにインポートする時、最初のセルに「�ｿ」の文字化けがでてきます。

テキストファイルの例文（Mac OSXのTextEditで見た場合）：

```
0dd6b4f419f3489a580846fb4ebe831b|one: [$numVotes$ more votes needed]
0dd6b4f419f3489a580846fb4ebe831b|other: [$numVotes$ more votes needed]
89e050644a71fbf8170e280f59fb8940: An error occurred during submission
a4c510816f6c806507bb528c240ed9a9: [closed]
2de9c2314772731359c387be3656bc19: Are you sure you want to award your bounty to this answer? THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!
```

複数のテキストファイルで同じ文字が現れてきます。手で治すには時間がかかりますので、自動的に方法がありますか？

Comment: テキストファイルというのはタブ区切りのファイルですか？　ぼくはそういうのを見たことがないですが、どのような手順でインポートしたんでしょうか？

Comment: テキストファイルがUTF-8のエンコーディングで保存されてます？あと、インポートしているテキストファイルの拡張子は.csvでしょうか？

Comment: @torus 何も区切りがないです。通常のテキストファイルですが、例文を編集で質問に追加します。インポートはエクセルのインポート機能で、自分で区切りや固定文字数で列を分けることができます。

Comment: @tomute UTF-8かどうかはどのように確認できますか？インポートファイルは通常のテキスト。編集で例文を入れます。

Comment: UTF-8 の BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark かな？　Mac の Excel でしょうか？　バージョンは？　TextEdit で名前を変えて ASCII で保存するとどうなります？

Comment: '�ｿ' はバイナリだと ef bf bd ef bd bf という並びのようで、これを検索してみたところ http://stackoverflow.com/a/6544206/124820 これが見つかりました。文字コードの変換の際にゴミが混ざることがあるようです。
テキストファイルを作っている人に、ASCII で作るようにお願いした方がいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 20, accepted):

おそらく、バイトオーダーマーク(BOM)のついたエンコーディングになっているのだとおもいます。バイトオーダーマークについて詳しくは以下を参照してください。

[バイトオーダーマーク - Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF)

UTF-16エンコーディングだと、プラットフォームによってエンディアンの違いが問題となるため、ファイルの先頭にエンディアンを識別するためのデータが追加されることがあります。そのデータのことをバイトオーダーマーク(BOM)といいます。

UTF-8エンコーディングはエンディアンの問題がないため、通常はBOMが付いていません。Mac OS Xなどで普通に「UTF-8」といえば「BOMなしUTF-8」となります。ただし、Unicodeの仕様としてはUTF-8にもBOMをつけることが許されていてその場合は「0xEF 0xBB 0xBF」が付加されます。

特に、Windows環境ではUTF-8にもBOMをつける傾向が多いようで、Windowsのメモ帳でUTF-8を選択して保存するとBOM付きUTF-8のファイルになります。

http://www.php-factory.net/trivia/03.php

今回の問題はMac版の ExcelがBOMありのUTF-8に対応していないのが原因だとおもいます。Microsoftの製品なんだから対応して欲しいところですが、仕方ないので テキストファイルの方を直すしかありません。

UNIXでの文字エンコーディングの変換は通常 iconv を使うのですが、iconvは BOMありのUTF-8に対応していないという問題があります。

http://yanok.net/2010/02/iconvutf-8bom.html

ちょっと古いツールですが、昔ながらの nkf を使うとBOMの変更操作も可能です。nkfは homebrew等でインストール可能です。

```
>brew install nkf
```

nkfでBOMを削除するには以下のようにします。

```
>nkf --overwrite --oc=UTF-8 test.txt
```

逆に、BOMを追加する場合は、以下のようにします。

```
>nkf --overwrite --oc=UTF-8-BOM test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

各行が「�ｿ」+「ascii文字列」というパターンであることが確定しているなら、「行の先頭からascii文字列以外を削除する」というパターンで除去することができます:

```sh
$ sed -i.bak 's/^[^[:alnum:]]*//' weird_*.txt
```

テスト:

```sh
$ echo -n -e "\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbd\xbf0dd" | sed '1 s/^[^[:alnum:]]*//' | hexdump -C
00000000  30 64 64 0a                                       |0dd.|
00000004
# 一文字増えているのは、sedが改行文字を最後に付加しているせい
```

文字化けしているバイト列をピンポイントで除去したい場合、Mac OS X の場合 gsed (GNU sed) でできます。バイト列をまず確認し:

```sh
$ echo -n -e "\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbd\xbf0dd" > weird.txt # テストファイルを作成
$ head -n1 weird.txt | hexdump -C # バイト列を確認
00000000  ef bf bd ef bd bf 30 64  64                       |......0dd|
00000009
```

置き換える:

```sh
# homebrewなどでgsedをインストール
$ gsed -i.bak 's/^\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbd\xbf//' weird.txt
$ cat weird.txt
0dd
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel(Mac)がBOM付きUnicodeに対応していないのが問題だと思います。GUIツールだとCotEditor(Mac)でBOMの除去ができます。

1. CotEditorでファイルを開く
2. メニュー -> フォーマット -> エンコーディング -> Unicode (UTF-16) を選択
3. ファイルを保存

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

BOM が付いているからというのが正解のようですが、何者かを確認できていたら解決が楽だった可能性があるので、それを調べる方法をどうぞ。

```
$ head -n1 target.txt |od -tcx1
```

こんな風にすると、ファイル先頭部分の文字コードを確認できます。`od`(1) の代わりに `hexdump`(1) などを利用してもいいですね。